# Why doesn't Simple HTML DOM find all elements?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I have next problem: try to parse this web-page: http://superdeals.aliexpress.com/en, but still without any result.

Need to take div class="pro-msg" which is inside li with class "list-items". However, not all the data is displayed on the page. The code looks like:

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$base = 'http://superdeals.aliexpress.com/en?spm=2114.11010108.21.1.v65LIL';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($str);

    $res=$html->find('div.pro-msg', 0)->outertext;
    echo $res;
```

Simple HTML DOM does not even see most right tags of the page, put another div - everything works . If i parse the entire page file_get_html, appears not the whole site page. Please tell me how to solve the problem.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Probably because most of the data appears to be pulled in via javascript after load. Simple cURL isn't going to hack it, nor is file_get_(html|contents).

Comment: thank you so much, and could you offer a solution?) Or give a tip... What should i do...

Comment: Either see if they have an API that will return the data you're after, or you'll need to find something that will render, run JS and return the complete markup afterwards. The latter way is not going to be pretty and will probably be prone to error / change at the websites whim.

Comment: You can either use phantomjs or figure out the ajax requests and make them yourself.